# SQL Cap Sum of 3 Numbers at 100

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, casting, precision

I've been tasked with an interesting problem. Basically, I have to compute 3 different percentages:

```
SELECT @LowPercent = CAST(ROUND((@LowCount / @ValidCount) * 100.0, 0) AS INT)
SELECT @MidPercent = CAST(ROUND((@MidCount / @ValidCount) * 100.0, 0) AS INT)
SELECT @HighPercent = CAST(ROUND((@HighCount / @ValidCount) * 100.0, 0) AS INT)
```

However, the sum of the percentages can't exceed 100.

Consider the following scenario: Suppose the intermediate calculations (e.g. @XXXCount/@ValidCount * 100.0) are computed as 1.8, 91.5, and 6.6. Rounding to 0 decimal places yields 2, 92, and 7 which sum to 101. Other than a simple "rule of thumb" such as "offset the highest number," is there a straight-forward way to address this requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `int` and use `float` ? :P

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. However, if I change to floating point, I could get percentages that include a large number of significant digits, e.g. 1.8258426966292135, 91.5858018386108274, 6.5883554647599591. I need the results rounded to 0 places.

Comment: what's wrong with "offset the highest number"?

Comment: i don't suppose anything's wrong with "offset the highest number". i enjoy hearing how others would solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why `int`?

---

If you really want to use int maybe the better option would to decrease the highest first.

*Or*

You could decrease the nearest to .5

---

If you need 0 places, the problem may occur if you do a round :) So you'll have to choose where to drop the unit.

Answer (score 2):

In line with hatchet's suggestion, how about leaving Low and High as is, and changing @MidPercent to:

```
SELECT @MidPercent = 100 - (@LowPercent + @HighPercent)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct way to get the result that you want. The only correct way to get the sum to be 100 is to not round the values in the first place.

The result that you have already is correct. Rounding each value gives you a rounding error. If you then add the values, the errors accumulate, and you get a total that is different from what you get by adding the unrounded values.

By changing the values to get a specific sum, you are introducing another error, but in an arbitrary value. If you still want to do that, you can just calculate the third value from the first two, it doesn't matter where you add the error because the result is incorrect either way. There is no correct way of adding an error like this.